# jQuery inArray and Javascript IndexOf returning partial matches. I need to check against a full match

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array that contains objects. I am trying to find out if an ID is missing from that array. The code I am using is returning partial matches such as allowing "1" to match "10", "11", "12","13" and so on. This occurs if I iterate as a string or I convert both the search term and the id as a number. For example this code:

```
var loadUserTemplate = function(json){
    var firstArray = json[0];
    var parsed = (JSON.parse(firstArray));
    var gridStack = $('.grid-stack-item');
    var plength = parsed.length;

    gridStack.each(function(index){
        var gridstackId = Number($(this).attr('data-custom-id'));

        for(var j=0; j < plength; j++){
            var doesNotContain = Number(parsed[j].id.indexOf(gridstackId));
            console.log(typeof doesNotContain);
            if(doesNotContain === -1){
                console.log(gridstackId + " is not in " + parsed[j].id);
            }
        }
}
```

Generates this in the console.log (I am only including the first number, notice how it finds 1 in 10 - 19):

```
number
1 is not in 2
number
1 is not in 3
number
1 is not in 4
number
1 is not in 5
number
1 is not in 6
number
1 is not in 8
number
1 is not in 9
number
1 is not in 20
number
1 is not in 22
number
1 is not in 23
number
1 is not in 24
number
1 is not in 25
number
1 is not in 26
```

I have tried jQuery(inArray) and indexOf with the same results. How do I find full matches, and not partial matches?

Update: parsed is firstArray parsed which is:

```
[{"x":"0","y":"0","width":"12","height":"5","id":"1"},{"x":"0","y":"5","width":"6","height":"2","id":"2"},{"x":"6","y":"5","width":"6","height":"2","id":"3"},{"x":"0","y":"7","width":"6","height":"2","id":"4"},{"x":"6","y":"7","width":"6","height":"2","id":"5"},{"x":"0","y":"9","width":"12","height":"8","id":"6"},{"x":"0","y":"17","width":"4","height":"6","id":"8"},{"x":"4","y":"17","width":"4","height":"6","id":"9"},{"x":"8","y":"17","width":"4","height":"6","id":"10"},{"x":"0","y":"23","width":"4","height":"6","id":"11"},{"x":"4","y":"23","width":"4","height":"6","id":"12"},{"x":"8","y":"23","width":"4","height":"6","id":"13"},{"x":"0","y":"29","width":"6","height":"8","id":"14"},{"x":"6","y":"29","width":"6","height":"8","id":"15"},{"x":"0","y":"37","width":"4","height":"6","id":"16"},{"x":"4","y":"37","width":"4","height":"6","id":"17"},{"x":"8","y":"51","width":"4","height":"6","id":"18"},{"x":"0","y":"43","width":"4","height":"6","id":"19"},{"x":"4","y":"51","width":"4","height":"6","id":"20"},{"x":"8","y":"57","width":"4","height":"6","id":"21"},{"x":"0","y":"57","width":"6","height":"8","id":"22"},{"x":"6","y":"63","width":"6","height":"8","id":"23"},{"x":"0","y":"65","width":"6","height":"8","id":"24"},{"x":"6","y":"71","width":"6","height":"8","id":"25"},{"x":"0","y":"79","width":"12","height":"10","id":"26"}]
```

gridstackId is the data-custom-id tag of the elements on the DOM.

Comment: Compare instead? `Number(parsed[j].id) === gridstackId` . FYI, `indexOf` always returns a number, so no need to pass the result to `Number`. What you are doing in `parsed[j].id.indexOf(gridstackId)` is checking whether the **string** (e.g.) `"10"` contains the character `"1"` which is of course true.

Comment: No, it does not return partial matches, `[10,11,14].indexOf(1)` is most definitively falsy (-1). You're just doing it wrong? What does `parsed[j].id` and `gridstackId` actually contain

Comment: @adeneo parsed is JSON.parse of the following data: [{"x":"0","y":"0","width":"12","height":"5","id":"1"},{"x":"0","y":"5","width":"6","height":"2","id":"2"},{"x":"6","y":"5","width":"6","height":"2","id":"3"},{"x":"0","y":"7","width":"6","height":"2","id":"4"},{"x":"6","y":"7","width":"6","height":"2","id":"5"}, etc... and gridstackId is the data id of elements on the DOM.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include examples of the data you are using.

Comment: don't paste code blobs into comments...update the actual question with formatted code

Comment: [Here is the documentation of `indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) btw.

Comment: So basically what you're doing is exactly what Felix is saying, `"10".indexOf("1")`

Comment: @charlietfl ok I updated it.

Comment: @FelixKling Your answer was correct. Do you want to answer it in a reply so I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `parsed[j].id` is a **string**, so `parsed[j].id.indexOf(gridstackId)` checks whether the value of `gridstackId` is *contained* in `parsed[j].id` (the value of `gridstackId` is converted to a string in the process as well).

If you want to check for *equality* you should use the comparison operator instead: `===`.

Since `gridstackId` is a number, you have to convert `parsed[j].id` to a number as well:

```
Number(parsed[j].id) === gridstackId
```

Alternatively, do *not* convert `$(this).attr('data-custom-id')` to a number, keep it as a string:

```
var gridstackId = $(this).attr('data-custom-id');
// ...
parsed[j].id === gridstackId;
```

---

To solve your problem though, namely checking whether an object with such an ID exists, you can use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
var gridstackId = $(this).attr('data-custom-id');
var exists = parsed.some(function(obj) {
  return obj.id === gridstackId;
});
```

`exists` will be `true` if there is at least one object for which the condition (ID equality) is fulfilled.